# Bash script average of iperf result

Tags: linux, parsing, iperf

I'm running iperf multiple times via the following command

```
iperf -c 1.1.1.1 -t 60 -w 6400 -f m >> iperf.log
```

sometimes with different arguments. The resulting `iperf.log` may look like this:

```
[ 3] local 2.2.2.2 port 51129 connected with 1.1.1.1 port 5001 
[ ID] Interval Transfer Bandwidth 
[ 3] 0.0-20.0 sec 1869 MBytes 784 Mbits/sec
[ 3] local 2.2.2.2 port 51130 connected with 1.1.1.1 port 5001 
[ ID] Interval Transfer Bandwidth 
[ 3] 0.0-15.0 sec 1445 MBytes 808 Mbits/sec
```

what i'd like to able to do is once it completed to have the average transfer rate outputted ie

```
 average ....... XXX Mbits/sec
```

Comment: So when you tried to do that, did something go wrong?  Is there a bug or design feature that you need help with?  Does `iperf` report the rate and you want to filter it?

Comment: sample output to iperf.log is    [  3] local 2.2.2.2 port 51129 connected with 1.1.1.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-20.0 sec  1869 MBytes    784 Mbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-15.0 sec  1445 MBytes    808 Mbits/sec i'd like to be able to add up 784 and 808 and get the average.

Comment: please learn to edit relevant details into your question above, rather than post it in replies to comments where it is unformatted. `awk` is a very good candidate to help with your problem. Read more at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . Good luck.

Comment: The idea of adding up 784 and 808 to get the bandwidth looks suspicious since transmit times are different. I assume correct average would be to add up transfer sizes and divide by transfer times.

Comment: yes that probably sounds a better way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is the way to go, you can try something like this:

`iperf -c 1.1.1.1 -t 60 -w 6400 -f m|awk -F 'MBytes' {'print $2'} >> iperf.log`

You just need to remove the empty lines now, that I will leave to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to start and stop it?  You might just want to use interval reporting (-i )  You can set i to 15 and set -t to samples desired * 15.

Comment: i think this is better as comment, not an answer (?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have enough points to add a comment.  Looks like I may have now.